# Could not parse the 'params' argument as valid JSON (PHP, cURL, REST)

Tags: php, json, rest

After executing the PHP Script, I am getting the following error – Any help is appreciated. Based on my understanding, I created an array based on the bugzilla documentation - Thanks in advance

https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/api/core/v1/bug.html#create-bug

{"code":32000,"error":true,"message":"Could not parse the 'params' argument as valid JSON. Error: malformed number (no digits after initial minus), at character offset 1

```
       $url ="http://localhost:8080/bugzilla/rest/bug";

       $data = array(
            "product" => "TestProduct",
            "component" => "TestComponent",
            "version" => "unspecified",
            "summary" => "'This is a test bug - please disregard",
            "alias" => "SomeAlias",
            "op_sys" => "All",
            "priority" => "P1",
            "rep_platform" => "All"
        );

        $str_data = json_encode($data);

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
                array("Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json")); 
        $username = 'ashish.sureka@in.abb.com';
        $password = 'incrc';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch); 

        echo $result
```

Comment: Does this still occur when you remove the single quote from the value in the `$data` array with the key `summary` ?

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I removed the single quote ' but still getting the same error

Comment: should you not use `$str_data` for your POSTFIELDS parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
```

which sends your array of data as a conventional `key=value` form submission, when you should have

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str_data);
                                         ^^^^^
```

which would send your JSON-encoded array instead.

Answer (score 1):

You send $data in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS but I think you need to give it $str_data which is encode in JSON

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to replace

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
```

with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str_data);
```

to transfer the json encoded array instead of the raw php array.